# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, pdo

Eu sei qual é o erro. Fala que o número de parâmetros não é igual ao de variáveis. Só não consigo encontrar onde que é o erro.

Se alguém conseguir enxergar algo que não enxerguei, ficarei grato ;D

P.S. eu sei que tem questão igual, mas quero saber onde ta meu erro, que por tudo onde que procurei, estava certo

```
    function editaLocalidade($IDLocalidade,$CNPJ, $inscMunicipal, $inscEstadual,$dataFundacao, $nomeLocalidade, $EndLogradouro, $EndComplemento,
                         $EndCep, $EndBairro, $EndCidade, $EndEstado,$telComercial1,$telComercial2,$notas,$_AtualizacaoUsuario ){
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_EmpresasLocalidades SET CNPJ=:CNPJ, InscMunicipal=:InscMunicipal, InscEstadual=:InscEstadual, DataFundacao=:DataFundacao,
        NomeLocalidade=:NomeLocalidade, EndLogradouro=:EndLogradouro, EndComplemento=:EndComplemento, EndCep=:EndCep,EndBairro=:EndBairro,
        EndCidade=:EndCidade,EndEstado =:EndEstado,TelComercial1 =:TelComercial1, TelComercial2 = :TelComercial2, Notas=:Notas,
        _AtualizacaoUsuario=:_AtualizacaoUsuario";
    $query .= "WHERE IDLocalidade = :IDLocalidade LIMIT 1";
    if($this->ConexaoMySQL()){
        try{
            $qry = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            $qry->bindValue(':CNPJ',$CNPJ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":InscMunicipal"      ,$inscMunicipal       ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":InscEstadual"       ,$inscEstadual        ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":DataFundacao"       ,$dataFundacao        ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":NomeLocalidade"     ,$nomeLocalidade      ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndLogradouro"      ,$EndLogradouro       ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndComplemento"     ,$EndComplemento      ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndCep"             ,$EndCep              ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndBairro"          ,$EndBairro           ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndCidade"          ,$EndCidade           ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":EndEstado"          ,$EndEstado           ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":TelComercial1"      ,$telComercial1       ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":TelComercial2"      ,$telComercial2       ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":Notas"              ,$notas               ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":_AtualizacaoUsuario",$_AtualizacaoUsuario ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qry->bindValue(":IDLocalidade"       ,$IDLocalidade        ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $qry->execute();
            if ($qry->rowCount() == 1) {
                return array('erro'=>'0', 'msg'=>'Localidade atualizada com sucesso!');
            }else{
                $ErroSQL = $qry->errorInfo();
                return array('erro'=>'1', 'msg'=>'Não foi alterado nenhum registro. Erro: '.$ErroSQL[1].': '.$ErroSQL[2]);
            }
        }catch (Exception $ex) {
            return array('erro'=>'1', 'msg'=>$ex->getMessage());
        };
    }else{
        return array('erro'=>'1', 'msg'=>'Não houve conexão com o Banco de Dados.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Duas coisas que eu faria: - colocar um espaço entre o WHERE assim: `$query .= "   WHERE` e usaria SEMPRE aspas duplas corrigindo para `":CNPJ"`

Comment: booooaaa hahahaha, deu certo kk